# Get values, multiply, and total with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my first time with Javascript and I'm stumped.

I have an array close to this...

```
var related_items = 
[{"id":"10", "qty": "16", "unitprice": "899.95"},
 {"id":"11", "qty": "12", "unitprice": "29.95"},
 {"id":"12", "qty": "15","unitprice": "49.95"}
];
```

What I need to do is, for each row, multiply the "qty" and the "unitprice"  and then total them all together.
So it would be (16x899.85)+(12x29.95)+(15x49.95) = total

I know I am not even close but this is what made sense to me, it obviously doesn't work...

```
var jsontotal = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < related_items.length; i++){
    jsonqty = parseInt(related_items[i].qty);   //this does return the qty
    janprice = related_items[i].unitprice;      //this returns null
    jsontotal = (jsonqty * jsonprice);            //obviously still null
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Typo: `janprice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array by taking `qty` and `unitprice` and get a total of the products.

BTW, you could use floats directly in the given data set instead of strings. Actually a special conversion to number is not necessary because of type casting to number (autoboxing) by using `*` operator.

```js
const
    items = [{ id: "10", qty: "16", unitprice: "899.95" }, { id: "11", qty: "12", unitprice: "29.95" }, { id: "12", qty: "15", unitprice: "49.95" }],
    total = items.reduce((t, { qty, unitprice }) => t + qty * unitprice, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can believe the answer was just one line of code. 
I appreciate you!